# Sequelize Transaction with async.parallel

Tags: asynchronous, transactions, sequelize.js, async.js

I want to use managed sequelize transactions with my async.parallel().

Right now, I do this:

```js
return sequelize.transaction(function (t) {
    return async.parallel([
      function(callback){ return func1(t, callback); },
      function(callback){ return func2(t, callback); }
    ], function(err){

      if(err){
        ...
      }
    });
  }).then(function(){
   ...
  }).catch(function(err){
    ...    
  });
```

If `func1` or `func2` fails before the other one, the transaction is rolled back. Then the next of the two functions will try to use the transaction, but then I get this error:

`Error: rollback has been called on this transaction(8b7f7cbc-b617-44fb-a9dd-906397e6f7ca), you can no longer use it.`

which makes sense.

What is the recommended way to work with sequelize transactions and async.parallel together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simply used the **unmanaged transactions** rather than the managed transactions and then it worked.

```js
return sequelize.transaction().then(function (t) {
    return async.parallel([
      function(callback){ return func1(t, callback); },
      function(callback){ return func2(t, callback); }
    ], function(err){
      if(err){
        return t.rollback();
      }
      
      return t.commit();
    });
  });
```

Note that now we use `sequelize.transaction().then(...)` instead of a callback function in transaction. Also note that `t.rollback()` return Promises so you can use `.then()` on them.

More info: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/transactions.html#unmanaged-transaction-then-callback-